# test_small_numbers: FAILED

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, pycharm, primes

I had to make a code, which will show if a number is prime. Every time I modify my code, git shows "test_small_numbers: FAILED".

I added several numbers and elifs but still the same

"""Primes identifier."""

```
def is_prime_number(number: int) -> bool: 
    """ Check if number (given in function parameter) is prime. 
    If number is prime -> return True 
    If number is not prime -> return False 

    :param number: number for check. 
    :return: boolean True if number is prime or False if number is not prime. """ 
    if number == 0:
        return False
    elif number == 1:
        return False
    elif number == 2:
        return True
    elif number % 2 == 0 or number % 3 == 0:
        return False
    elif number % 2 > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(is_prime_number(2))  # -> True
    print(is_prime_number(89))  # -> True
    print(is_prime_number(23))  # -> True
    print(is_prime_number(4))  # -> False
    print(is_prime_number(7))  # -> True
    print(is_prime_number(88))  # -> False
    print(is_prime_number(1))  # -> False
    print(is_prime_number(33))  # -> False
    print(is_prime_number(0))  # -> False
```

test_small_numbers: passed

Comment: You haven't given us any context here. But, for starters, your function currently returns `True` for `input is_prime_number(25)`. It doesn't sound like your method of checking for primality is complete...

Comment: [How to create the most compact mapping n → isprime(n) up to a limit N?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1801391)

Comment: You have not shown us the test code or the prime numbers function. We need that to help you.

Comment: """Primes identifier."""


def is_prime_number(number: int) -> bool:
    """
    Check if number (given in function parameter) is prime.

    If number is prime -> return True
    If number is not prime -> return False

    :param number: number for check.
    :return: boolean True if number is prime or False if number is not prime.
    """

Comment: your `is_prime_number` is not a valid test. Example: 25

Comment: Looks like it fails on 3 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is specifically checking for multiples of 2 and 3, though it does not do it very efficiently.

You could improve it by writing something like:

```
"""
:param number: number for check. 
:return: boolean True if number is prime or False if number is not prime. 
"""
if number <= 1:
    return False  # There are no primes less than 2
elif number % 2 == 0:
    return (number == 2)  # 2 is the only even prime number.
elif number % 3 == 0:
    return (number == 3)  # 3 is the only prime multiple of 3.
else:
  #
  # You need work here to fix problems with 25, 35, 49, 77, 121 etc.
  # There are a lot of resources for research into this question.
  #
```

My python is not good, so do check my code for syntax errors.

To give you a hint, once you have removed 2 and 3, all the remaining prime numbers are of the form 6n-1 or 6n+1.  That can help you avoid some useless checking.